# Splash screen animation

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, imageview

I made a splash activity before my app's main activity. It has a movieview and an animated imageview. I have two problems with the imageview:

1. Before the fade-in animation starts the image is visible.
2. During the animation a see the frames. ( And it is not because of the emulator, I also tested it on a Sony Xperia SP.)

My java:

```
package com.koostamas.tbbt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView circle;
private Animation anim;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    VideoView loading = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView_loading);
    circle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_circle);

    loading.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.koostamas.tbbt/raw/splash_loading");
    loading.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    loading.start();

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   if (hasFocus)
      circle.startAnimation(anim);
}

Thread thread = new Thread(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            sleep(5000);
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

};
{
thread.start();

}

}
```

Please help me solve these problems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set the content view after you start the animation? Or perhaps, in your content view, make the initial value transparent, and then use your animation to change the opacity?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the onWindowFocusChanged register on the videoView's  setOnCompletionListener. there you can start your animation.
To call the next activity use :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
   public void run()  
  { startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        finish(); }
} , animationTime);
```